# How copy a specific file from all windows-users appdata\Roaming

Tags: powershell, shell

I need to copy from each windows-user a specific file in appdata\Roaming to c:\temp"user profile"
This is the code

```
$users = (gci $env:systemDrive\users).FullName
foreach ($user in $users) {
write-host $user
Copy-Item -Path "$user\Appdata\Roaming\Notepad++\config.xml" -Destination "C:\temp\$user" -Force -Recurse -ERRORACTION SILENTLYCONTINUE

}
```

I don´t know why but it looks like the path it´s not supported. **How can I create a folder for each user in Temp with the file that I´m coopying from appdata\Roaming ?** FYI: In the future I will need to do the opposite.

**This is the error: **Copy-Item : The specified path format is not supported.**
**

I tried to find some solutions on the internet but none was successful.

Comment: What do you get when you display `$users` or `$user`? When I do it on my computer, I get the full path, including drive, so that your destination ends up looking like `C:\temp\C:\Users\example`, which is indeed bogus.

Answer (score 0):

> `$users = (gci $env:systemDrive\users).FullName`

This stores *full paths* in `$users` whereas you're only looking to use the directory *name* in  `"C:\temp\$user"`

Also, you'll need to first make sure that the user-specific target directories in `C:\temp` *exist* before you can copy files there.

Therefore:

```
$users = Get-ChildItem $env:systemDrive\users # gci is short for Get-ChildItem
foreach ($user in $users) {
  Write-Host $user
  Copy-Item -LiteralPath "$($user.FullName)\Appdata\Roaming\Notepad++\config.xml" `
    -Destination (New-Item -Type Directory -Force "C:\temp\$($user.Name)") `
    -Force -Recurse -ERRORACTION SILENTLYCONTINUE
}
```

Note:

- Instead of using the `.FullName` properties of the directory items returned by `Get-ChildItem`, the items are stored as-is in `$users`, which allows selective access to their properties later, namely via `$user.FullName` and `$user.Name`.

  - Enclosing these property references in `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), is necessary in order to embed them in an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)
- [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) `-Type Directory` with `-Force` returns either a preexisting directory with the given path or creates it.